# Laravel / MySQL console different results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am using laravel and I have this method inside one model.

When I run the query in PhpMyAdmin or in the MySQL console I get the expected result.

When running it in Laravel, I always get the same row which doesn't even fulfill the "where" statements in the query. Same luck when using `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
public static function getPotentialMatch($id, $genderId = NULL)
        {
            $query = "SELECT
                student.id AS id,
                (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM    matches AS m WHERE   m.local_student_id = student.id) AS matches
            FROM
                users AS user
            JOIN students AS student
                ON user.id = student.user_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN languages_student AS ls
                ON student.id = ls.student_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN languages AS language
                ON ls.language_id = language.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN courses AS course
                ON student.course_id = course.id
            WHERE ls.language_id IN 
                    (   
                        SELECT ls.language_id AS languageId
                        FROM languages_student AS ls
                        JOIN students AS student1
                            ON ls.student_id = student1.id
                        JOIN users AS user1
                            ON student1.user_id = user1.id
                        WHERE student1.id = " . $id . "
                    )
            AND student.course_id IN
                    (
                        SELECT courseR.id AS affinityId
                        FROM courses AS course 
                        JOIN course_affinities 
                            ON course.id = course_affinities.course1_id 
                            OR course.id = course_affinities.course2_id 
                        JOIN courses AS courseR 
                            ON (courseR.id = course_affinities.course1_id 
                                AND courseR.id <> course.id) 
                            OR (courseR.id = course_affinities.course2_id 
                                AND courseR.id <> course.id) 
                        WHERE course.id  IN 
                                (
                                    SELECT student.course_id 
                                    FROM students AS student 
                                    WHERE student.id = " . $id . "
                                )
                    )
            AND student.incoming = 0
            AND student.active = 1
            AND (
                    SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    matches AS m
                    WHERE   m.local_student_id = student.id
                ) < 3
            ";

            if ($genderId != NULL) {
                $query .= " AND student.gender_id = " . $genderId;
            }

            $query .= " ORDER BY (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM    matches AS m WHERE   m.local_student_id = student.id)
                        LIMIT 1";

            return DB::select(DB::raw($query));
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the query is composed correctly? Because you have an `if` statement there that adds a condition. Are you expecting that condition to be added for the results to match? And if so, are you sure it is? Otherwise I doubt there is any reason for an identical query to return a different result set.

Comment: You were right! I was passing the parameter the wrong way. Thanks a lot!
Is there a way of marking your comment as the correct answer?